# JAXRS annotations: Interpret and apply behavor at runtime

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jsr311

I have the following scenario in REST and for certain reasons, I cannot change the design:

- **WAR1** is deployed first (Context: **/app1**).
- **WAR2** (context: **/app2**), (WAR3 and so on) having JAXRS annotations on certain classes is deployed later
- WAR1 needs to behave like a proxy handling all the calls. By this I mean WAR1 needs to be informed about WAR2's RESTful resources (say /res1) during its deployment.
- Call to **/app1/app2/res1** will delegate it to WAR2. I would like this be a Java call rather than REST (http).

Please feel free to correct me, but my question from the above scenario is: Is it possible to read/understand the JAXRS annotations of a WAR and apply them dynamically over another war at runtime ?

I'm using Jersey for JAXRS implementation

Thanks in advance

Comment: Link the wars and then try in your dev set-up , if it works, it will work everywhere.

Comment: "Link" the wars ? Could you be more specific ?